# Ajax, UTF8 encode from array, JSON: getting crazy with letters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, utf-8

I have a PHP function that return an array of tweets in this mode:

```
foreach ($tweets as $key => $value)
{
    $result[]['text'] = utf8_encode($value['text']);
}
echo header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($result);
```

The html is set in UTF8, directly from framework.

The resulting JSON has this kinda of encoding (I presume they are correct, btw it is a simple extract)

```
<strong><a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23localit\u00c3\u00a0&src=hash\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">#localit\u00c3\u00a0<\/a>
```

How you can note, instead of "località" it prints `localit\u00c3\u00a0`

But, terribly, this is the output on browser:

[image]

I did try to remove or add the

```
echo header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

No change at all.

This is the snippet of code that I use to get the array from PHP:

```
$.ajax({
            url         : location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/tweet_list',
            async       : true,
            dataType    : 'json'
        }).done(function (result) {
```

Do you have some hint for me to show to my users "località" instead of localitÃ   ?

Looking in google, I saw in another answer that that value in UTF8 is correct and now the client must be interprete it, but I see wrong // bad chars in all browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari)...

Thank you very very much!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8.  I had to use that one one pesky project that was using Excel and the internal methods weren't cutting it.

Comment: Are you sure `$value['text']` isn't already utf-8? To me it looks like you encode an already utf-8 encoded string another time.

Comment: @t.niese I'm sure, because whitout the utf8_encode I'm getting  `mod_fcgid: stderr: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument `

Comment: @Mark Your library works like a charm! @ t.niese probably you are right... The apache error taken on wrong way. Probably the string is twice encoded! With Mark library solved !